# Injecting Generic Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I am Injecting GenericRepository into BL service that calles it in order to get data from entity framework. No Exception is thrown until I am trying to add the other BL Service as scoped I get the following Exception:

> System.AggregateExceptionHResult=0x80131500 Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BL.Interfaces.IDoorsBL Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BL.Services.DoorsBL': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'DAL.Repositories.GenericRepository[DAL.Models.Door]'.)

StackTrace:

```
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider..ctor(ICollection`1 
    serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in source\repos\IntimidatorServer\IntimidatorServer\Program.cs:line 48

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]

Inner Exception 1:

InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: BL.Interfaces.IDoorsBL Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: BL.Services.DoorsBL': Unable  resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'DAL.Repositories.GenericRepository`1[DAL.Models.Door]'.

Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' while attempting to activate 'DAL.Repositories.GenericRepository DAL.Models.Door
```

GeneriRepository:

```cs
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public async Task<T> CreateAsync(T obj)
    {
        await _context.Set<T>().AddAsync(obj);
        return obj;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(params object[] keys)
    {
        var entityToDelete = await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(keys);
        if (entityToDelete != null)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Remove(entityToDelete);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        return filter == null ? await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync() : 
        (IEnumerable<T>)await _context.Set<T>().Where(filter).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T> GetAsync(params object[] keys)
    {
        return await _context.Set<T>().FindAsync(keys);
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public Task<bool> UpdateAsync(T obj)
    {
        try
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Attach(obj);
            _context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
}
```

DoorsBL:

```cs
public class DoorsBL : IDoorsBL
{
    private IGenericRepository<Door> _repository;

    public DoorsBL(IGenericRepository<Door> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Door>> GetAvailableDoors()
    {
        return await _repository.GetAllAsync(d => d.IsAvailble == true);
    }
}
```

program.cs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionString")));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDoorsBL, DoorsBL>();
```

dbcontext:

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public AppDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public DbSet<Door> Doors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Intimidator> Intimidators { get; set; }
}
```

I have no idea what is cuasing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>` registers `AppDbContext` not `DbContext`, change the repository accordingly:

```cs
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public GenericRepository(AppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
   // ...
}
```

P.S.

Generic repos on top of EF Core context can be considered [anti-pattern](https://bigmachine.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/).

Comment: Can I ask you how would your implement it, if not generic repository?

Comment: @tal one way would be just to use context in services because it already implements repository + UoW patterns. I personally tend to use CQRS splitting data access from services into separate queries and commands. Though personally I don't have that much strong feelings about repositories on top of EF Core.